# Code blocks errors (No such file or directory) during compile

Tags: macos, c++, code-blocks

I am new to programming and recently installed codeblocks for c++ program.

When I run my code it give a error in terminal showing that "No such file or directory" on my macbook but it is pretty fine on my windows machine.

I figured out that the "resource compiler" located in 'toolchain executable' is showing blank in my macbook but in Windows it shows windres.exe.

Is that the cause of my problem and how to I fix it?

[image]

Please help me to solve my problem.